# JavaScript skips over document.write to go to window.prompt?

Tags: javascript, document.write

This code is suppose to go back and forth between window.prompt() and document.write(), but instead it goes through all the window.prompt() messages and iterates as long as it has to, then it dumps all the document.write output at the exit of the while loop.
What can be done to go back and forth?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>gasMilage</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript">

            var gasNow;
            var distanceNow;
            var mpgNow;
            var gasOverall;
            var distanceOverall;
            var mpgOverall;
            var answer;

            answer = "yes";

            gasOverall = parseInt(0);
            distanceOverall = parseInt(0);

            while(answer == "yes"){

            gasNow = window.prompt(
            "Enter the gallons of gas used: ")
            gasNow = parseInt(gasNow);

            distanceNow = window.prompt(
            "Enter the distance traveled in miles: ")
            distanceNow = parseInt(distanceNow);

            mpgNow = parseInt(distanceNow / gasNow);

            document.writeln(
            "Your current mpg is " + mpgNow + "<br />");

            gasOverall = gasNow + gasOverall;
            distanceOverall = distanceNow + distanceOverall;
            mpgOverall = parseInt(distanceOverall/gasOverall);

            document.writeln(
            "Your overall mpg is " + mpgOverall + "<br />");

            answer = window.prompt(
            "If you want to add more values, type yes.")
            }

        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean to say you want to call document.writeln after completing a prompt?

Comment: You just want to write after each prompt?

Comment: After each prompt you can add a delay using setTimeout and pass empty function.

Comment: I just wanted it to read and execute line by line, you know, the definition of what JS should do.  I wasn't familiar with the JS window.prompt executing faster than the HTML document.write.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is happening because the prompts are coming in too fast and the DOM doesn't have time to write since there's a pending prompt request going on. The solution to this is to put timeouts on your prompt methods.

But since your doing a while loop here, it's going to do the first prompt again without waiting for the timeout. So instead of a while loop, just wrap it in a function and recursively call it if the last prompt is yes.

Try it on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3av7u4s/)

```js
(function query() {
    gasNow = window.prompt(
    "Enter the gallons of gas used: ")
    gasNow = parseInt(gasNow);

    distanceNow = window.prompt(
    "Enter the distance traveled in miles: ")
    distanceNow = parseInt(distanceNow);

    mpgNow = parseInt(distanceNow / gasNow);

    document.writeln(
    "Your current mpg is " + mpgNow + "<br />");

    gasOverall = gasNow + gasOverall;
    distanceOverall = distanceNow + distanceOverall;
    mpgOverall = parseInt(distanceOverall/gasOverall);

    document.writeln(
    "Your overall mpg is " + mpgOverall + "<br />");

    setTimeout(() => {
        answer = window.prompt(
        "If you want to add more values, type yes.")
        if(answer === 'yes') query();
    }, 1);

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

After each document.write you can add a delay. This will give time for the document to get rendered.